If $X\sim\mathcal N(x,\Sigma)$, what is $\operatorname E\left[\left\|\Sigma^{-1}(X-x)\right\|^2\right]$?
The question is in the title. If $\Sigma=\sigma^2I_d$, then we easily calculate $$\operatorname E\left[\left\|\Sigma^{-1}(X-x)\right\|^2\right]=\frac1{\sigma^2}\tag1.$$ However, the general case seems to be more complicated. The natural generalization would be $\Sigma^{-2}$. In any case, how can we calculate this?

Hint: If $X\sim N(x, \Sigma)$, then $X = x + AZ$ for some $A$ with $AA^T = \Sigma$, where $Z \sim N(0, I)$.

The law of $X \sim \mathcal{N}(x, \Sigma)$ can be realized via
$$ X = x + \Sigma^{1/2} Z $$
where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_d)$ and $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is the unique PSD square root of $\Sigma$. Hence, assuming $\Sigma$ is PD, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[\|\Sigma^{-1}(X - x)\|^2]
&= \mathbf{E}[\|\Sigma^{-1}(X - x)\|^2] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\|\Sigma^{-1/2}Z\|^2] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[Z^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}Z] \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1}).
\end{align*}
This is equal to the sum of reciprocal of the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$.
In general, if $\Sigma$ is allowed to be PSD (so that $X$ is allowed to have a degenerate normal distribution), a slight modification of the above computation tells that
$$ \mathbf{E}[\|\Sigma^{-1}(X - x)\|^2] = \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^+), $$
where $\Sigma^+$ is the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse. The above value is also equal to the sum of reciprocal of the non-zero eigenvalues of $\Sigma$.
Below is a Monte-Carlo simulation, comparing the sample mean of $10^6$ samples of $\|\Sigma^{-1}(X - \mu)\|^2$ from $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $\mu = (1, 2)^{\top}$ and $\Sigma = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. The simulated sample mean, $5.99535$, turns out to be very close to this exact value $\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1}) = 6$, confirming the above computation in this case.


What am I missing? Your result seems to contradict my claim about the case $\Sigma=\sigma^2I_d$, sine $\operatorname{tr}\Sigma^{-1}=\frac d{\sigma^2}$ instead.

@0xbadf00d I don't know how you reached your claim, but the correct answer is indeed $\frac{d}{\sigma^2}$ when $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I_d)$. The answer must scale with the dimension $d$, since it must be proportional to the "average square length of a standard normal vector".

Yeah, you're right. I simply dropped the $d$ in my calc, since it didn't matter for me.
